# Input Value by User in google sheet with dialog box (google script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a dialog box with google script which asked me to enter a value or a name to rename a google sheet or a google slide but I didn't achieved it and I need some helps..

If you have any ideas, I'll take it !

Thanks in advance.
Anthony

Comment: Well, check the google app script doc for it...

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done in Sheets by use of [Prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs). Your code could look somewhat like this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Extra tools').addItem('Rename sheet', 'renameSheet').addToUi();
}

function renameSheet() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter the new name for the sheet');
  var newName = result.getResponseText();
  if (!newName) return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setName(newName);
}
```

The idea is that:

1. Your `onOpen()` function is automatically executed when opening the Spreadsheet. What this does it to create an additional menu item with the name "Extra tools". Upon clicking it you will find another button called "Rename sheet". Clicking this button will run the `renameSheet()` function declared right below.
2. The `renameSheet()` function is executed. It creates a prompt (see image below) asking the user for a new name for the sheet.
3. After the prompt lifecycle is completed (the user has inputted a value) the response is obtained, and the sheet is renamed.

[image: prompt ui example]

If what you want is to modify the name of the file, rather than the name of the sheet, you will have to modify the `renameSheet()` function as follows:

```js
function renameSheet() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter the new name for the sheet');
  var newName = result.getResponseText();
  if (!newName) return;
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setName(newName);
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to use this code in your Slides document (and the intended behaviour was to update the file name) you will simply have to use the above `onOpen()` function along with the last `renameSheet()` function, replacing every instance of `SpreadsheetApp` for `SlidesApp` and doing some other modifications. It would look like this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('Extra tools').addItem('Rename Slides document', 'renameSlides').addToUi();
}

function renameSlides() {
  var result = SlidesApp.getUi().prompt('Enter the new name for the slides document');
  var newName = result.getResponseText();
  if (!newName) return;
  var fileId = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setName(newName);
}
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) => "Answer well-asked questions"

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for your contribution. I will carefully reflect on this.

Comment: @carlesgg97 Thanks for taking the time to help someone out. I'm sorry your answer was downvoted even though it is, in fact, helpful and you clearly put some time into it. That said, I would encourage you to request more information from the asker before answering–understand what they've tried and what their exact problem is.